# Does the Phone Gap storage API support prepared statements for SQL lite

Tags: sqlite, cordova, storage, prepared-statement

I am able to insert two records into the table "MY_TABLE" using the code below, via the Phone Gap storage API using sql lite.

```
var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);                                      
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
    tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (first_name,last_name) VALUES ('joe','smith'),('bob','wilson')");
    }, errorCB, function(){
    //success code
    });
```

Does the Phone Gap API have a mechanism like prepared statements to deal with insertions that have characters like single parenthesis that can confuse my INSERT statement?

Answer (score 3):

Of course:

```
tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO MyTable (FirstName, LastNname) VALUES (?, ?)",
              ["Bobby", "Tables"]);
```

Comment: Hey CL thanks so much for your answer! Any chance you could explain the syntax a little. For example what role are the question marks playing, how does this guard against single parenthesis, and how can this be extended to multiple row inserts?

Comment: Any string can be replaced with a [parameter](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#varparam). When the string comes from user input, this protects against [SQL injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) like [this](http://xkcd.com/327/). There is nothing special about multi-row inserts.